# How to wait for SSE/EventStream in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, event-stream

In Cypress framework `cy.wait(alias)` is commonly used for test synchronization.

What is the recommended way (example) to wait if result is expected in SSE (Server Side Event), instead of normal request/response.